# Search SQL DB's For A Specific Word

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am completely new to SQL and have no experience what so ever in it so please bear with me with this question.

I need to know if it is possible to search a SQL database for a specific word and if so how?

We are currently going through a rebranding project and I need to look in our CMS (Content Management System) database for all reference to an email address.  All I need to search for is:

*.co.uk*

Below is a screenshot of the database in question with all the containing tables, I just cant get me head around SQL and I have had no joy on Google trying to find the answer.

[image]

I need to search everything in this database but I don't know what tables, views, column names etc the content sits in as it's all spread across them all.

There are other tables I need to search but hopefully an answer will be provided which I can modify to search these.

Comment: You could try SQL Search, a free tool from Redgate: http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search/

Comment: @NickyvV I have downloaded it but it says there are no matches for every word I search for even the word 'and'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DB's aren't really meant for such vague search descriptions, you should have some definition or model or requirement specs to describe where values like that could exist.

But of course, you could opt for an insanely slow method of doing it by using dynamic SQL.

I made this right fast and just tested it fast, but it should work:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#SEARCHTABLE') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #SEARCHTABLE

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#RESULTS') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #RESULTS

CREATE TABLE #SEARCHTABLE (ROWNUM INT IDENTITY(1,1), SEARCHCLAUSE VARCHAR(2000)  COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT)

INSERT INTO #SEARCHTABLE (SEARCHCLAUSE)
SELECT 'SELECT TOP 1 '''+TAB.name+''', '''+C.name+''' 
FROM ['+S.name+'].['+TAB.name+'] 
WHERE '
    +CASE WHEN T.name <> 'xml' 
        THEN '['+C.name+'] LIKE ''%.co.uk%'' AND ['+C.name+'] LIKE ''%@%''' 
        ELSE 'CAST(['+C.name+'] AS VARCHAR(MAX)) LIKE ''%.co.uk%'' AND CAST(['+C.name+'] AS VARCHAR(MAX)) LIKE ''%@%''' 
        END AS SEARCHCLAUSE
FROM sys.tables TAB
JOIN sys.schemas S on S.schema_id = TAB.schema_id
JOIN sys.columns C on C.object_id = TAB.object_id
JOIN sys.types T on T.user_type_id = C.user_type_id
WHERE TAB.type_desc = 'USER_TABLE'
AND (T.name LIKE '%char%' OR 
    T.name LIKE '%xml%')
AND CASE WHEN C.max_length = -1 THEN 10 ELSE C.max_length END >= 6 -- To only search through sufficiently long column

CREATE TABLE #RESULTS (ROWNUM INT IDENTITY(1,1), TABLENAME VARCHAR(256) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT, COLNAME VARCHAR(256) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT)

DECLARE @ROWNUM_NOW INT, @ROWNUM_MAX INT, @SQLCMD VARCHAR(2000), @STATUSSTRING VARCHAR(256)

SELECT @ROWNUM_NOW = MIN(ROWNUM), @ROWNUM_MAX = MAX(ROWNUM) FROM #SEARCHTABLE

WHILE @ROWNUM_NOW <= @ROWNUM_MAX
BEGIN
    SELECT @SQLCMD = SEARCHCLAUSE FROM #SEARCHTABLE WHERE ROWNUM = @ROWNUM_NOW

    INSERT INTO #RESULTS
    EXEC(@SQLCMD)

    SET @STATUSSTRING = CAST(@ROWNUM_NOW AS VARCHAR(25))+'/'+CAST(@ROWNUM_MAX AS VARCHAR(25))+', time: '+CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 120)

    RAISERROR(@STATUSSTRING, 10, 1) WITH NOWAIT

    SELECT @ROWNUM_NOW = @ROWNUM_NOW + 1
END

SET NOCOUNT ON

SELECT 'This table and column contains strings ".co.uk" and a "@"' INFORMATION, TABLENAME, COLNAME FROM #RESULTS

-- Uncomment to drop the created temp tables
--IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#SEARCHTABLE') IS NOT NULL
--  DROP TABLE #TABLECOLS

--IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#RESULTS') IS NOT NULL
--  DROP TABLE #RESULTS
```

What it does, it search the DB for all user-created tables with their schemas, which have (n)char/(n)varchar/xml columns of a sufficient length, and search each of them one by one until at least one match is found, then it moves to the next one on the list. Match is defined as any string or XML cast as string, which contains the text ".co.uk" and an "@"-sign somewhere in there.

It will show the progress of  the script (how many searchable TABLE.COLUMN combinations are have been found and which one on that list is currently running, as well as the current timestamps down to seconds) on the messages tab. When ready, it will show you all the tables and column names that contained at least one match.

So from that list, you'll have to search through the tables and columns manually to find exactly how many and what kinds of matches there are, and what it is you actually want to do.

Edit: Again I disregarded using sysnames for sysobjects, but I'll modify later if needed.

Answer (score 1):

I threw together a quick query that seems to work for me:

```
--Search for a word in the current database
SET NOCOUNT ON;

--First make a hit list of possible tables/ columns
DECLARE @HitList TABLE (
    Id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    TableName VARCHAR(255),
    SchemaName VARCHAR(255),
    ColumnName VARCHAR(255));
INSERT INTO 
    @HitList (
        TableName,
        SchemaName,
        ColumnName)
SELECT 
    t.name, 
    s.name,
    c.name 
FROM 
    sys.tables t 
    INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON c.object_id = t.object_id
    INNER JOIN sys.schemas s ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
WHERE 
    c.system_type_id = 167;

--Construct Dynamic SQL
DECLARE @Id INT = 1;
DECLARE @Count INT;
SELECT @Count = COUNT(*) FROM @HitList;
DECLARE @DynamicSQL VARCHAR(1024);
WHILE @Id <= @Count
BEGIN
    DECLARE @TableName VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE @SchemaName VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE @ColumnName VARCHAR(255);
    SELECT @TableName = TableName FROM @HitList WHERE Id = @Id;
    SELECT @SchemaName = SchemaName FROM @HitList WHERE Id = @Id;
    SELECT @ColumnName = ColumnName FROM @HitList WHERE Id = @Id;
    SELECT @DynamicSQL = 'SELECT * FROM [' + @SchemaName + '].[' + @TableName + '] WHERE [' + @ColumnName + '] LIKE ''%co.uk%''';
    --PRINT @DynamicSQL;
    EXECUTE (@DynamicSQL);
    IF @@ROWCOUNT != 0
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'We have a hit in ' + @TableName + '.' + @ColumnName + '!!';
    END;
    SELECT @Id = @Id + 1;
END;
```

Basically it makes a list of any VARCHAR columns (you might need to change this to include NVARCHARs if you have Unicode text columns - just change the test for system type id from 167 to 231) then performs a search for each one.  When you run this from management studio switch to the messages pane to see the hits and just ignore the results.

It will be slow if your database is any sort of size... but then that is to be expected?